# GridViewColumn CellTemplate Conditional Visibility of Text Run

Tags: c#, wpf

In below snippet I would like to hide the `Run Text` when the second property `Prop2` is null or empty. What is the best way of doing this?

```
<GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock >
            <Run Text="{Binding Prop1}"></Run>
            <Run Text=" {"></Run> <----- Collapse/Hide when Prop2 is null or empty
            <Run Text="{Binding Prop2}"></Run><----- Collapse/Hide when Prop2 is null or empty
            <Run Text="}"></Run><----- Collapse/Hide when Prop2 is null or empty
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `StringFormat` and `TargetNullValue`.

```
<Run Text="{Binding Prop1}"></Run>
<Run Text="{Binding Prop2, StringFormat={}{{{0}}}, TargetNullValue={}}"></Run>
```